# Whatsapp url query string parametrs

Tags: web, whatsapp, whatsapi

What is the pourpose of **&source=**, **&data=** and **&app_absent** query strings parametres in the whatsapp url (*https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXX&text=**&source=&data=&app_absent=***) ?

It is possible to track WhatsApp message's source filling these parameters ?

If it is, where I can see those information ? On Whatsapp business App ?

Comment: ¿Did you find the answer?

Comment: I didn't find it yet @JuanSebastianPrietoBustaman :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***&app_absent=1*** Is used to replace the "Continue to Chat" button by "Download" button to allow user to download WhatsApp for current OS.